# Mandatory hash argument in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a step-by-step Ruby-on-Rails tutorial and using Ruby 2.0.0. At some
point, the same file input works in the tutorial video but
produces an error message in my app.

Here is the code (for a comment controller) :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task_id])
    @comment = @task.comments.build(comment_params)

     if @task.save
         redirect_to @task, notice: 'Comment successfully posted.' 
     else
        redirect_to @task, alert: 'Comment not  posted.' 
     end

  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body)
    # {comment : {name:,email:,body:}}
  end

end
```

The error message I get when trying to create a comment is

```
ArgumentError in CommentsController#create 

When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

The line causing the error is `@task = Task.new(params[:task_id])`

How should I fix this ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't create any `Task` in this action, but you should find your task and assign new `Comment` to it. So instead of `new`, you should use `find`:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
```